# I am confused with ids and keys

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Here, I am trying to add subtasks to tasks. The idea is when the "tray-plus" button is clicked, it brings up a little window where I can add the text for the subtask text. When I hit save, that text should be added to the elements of the corresponding task in my dictionary. For example:

```
{'Task1': ['Subtask1.1', 'Subtask1.2'], 'Taks2': []}
```

Here, I added 'Subtask1.2' to Task1.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget,OneLineAvatarIconListItem,IconRightWidget, OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton, MDFlatButton


class TaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class SubTaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, task_text="", **kwargs):
        super(SubTaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.subtask_text.text = task_text

allTasks = {}
class MyApp(MDApp):

        database_file = 'database2.txt'
        task_list_dialog = None
        subtask_list_dialog = None
        allTasks = {}

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main2.kv')

    def load_tasks_from_file(self):
        file = open("database2.txt", "r")
        lines = file.readlines()
        task = None
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if line[0] == "*":
                task = line[1:]
                allTasks[task] = []
            else:
                subtask = line[1:]
                allTasks[task].append(subtask)
        print(allTasks)


    def on_start(self):
        self.load_tasks_from_file()
    #     self.write_to_file()
        self.view_tasks(allTasks)


    def task_dialog(self):
        if self.task_list_dialog:
            self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

        self.task_list_dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Create a Task",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=TaskDialogContent()
        )
        self.task_list_dialog.open()

    def subtask_dialog(self, key):
        if self.subtask_list_dialog:
            self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

        self.subtask_list_dialog = MDDialog(
            title=f"Add a subtask to {key} ",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=SubTaskDialogContent()
        )
        self.subtask_list_dialog.open()

    def add_task(self, taskname):
        allTasks[taskname] = []
        self.view_tasks(allTasks)

    def add_subtask(self, key):
        subtask_text = self.subtask_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.subtask_text.text
        allTasks[key].append(subtask_text)

        print("After adding the subtask")
        print(allTasks)

    def view_tasks(self, allTasks):
        print(allTasks) 
        self.root.ids.container.clear_widgets()
        for key in allTasks:
            item = OneLineListItem(
                MDIconButton(
                    icon="tray-plus",
                    pos_hint={"center_x": .92, "center_y": 0.5},
                    on_release = lambda instance, key = key: self.subtask_dialog(key)
                ),
                MDIconButton(
                    icon="trash-can-outline",
                    pos_hint={"right": 1, "center_y": 0.5},
                    on_release = lambda instance, key = key: self.delete_task(key)
                ),
                text= key,
                on_release = lambda instance, key = key: self.view_subtasks(key)
                )
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)

    def view_subtasks(self, key): 
        print("works")


    def delete_task(self,key):
        allTasks.pop(key, None)
        print(allTasks) #printing the tasks after deletion


    def close_task_dialog(self, *args):
        self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

    def close_subtask_dialog(self):
        self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = MyApp()
        app.run()
```

Here is the kivy file

```
MDFloatLayout:
MDLabel:
    id: task_label
    halign: "center"
    markup: True
    text:"[b][u][size=48]Your Task Manager[/size][/u][/b]"
    pos_hint: {"y": 0.45}

ScrollView:
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5}
    size_hint: 0.9, 0.8
    MDList:
        id: container

MDFloatingActionButton:
    icon: "plus-thick"
    on_release: app.task_dialog()
    elevation_normal: 12
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "y": 0.04}

<TaskDialogContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: task_text
            hint_text: "Add a task ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: (app.add_task(task_text.text), app.close_task_dialog())


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: (app.add_task(task_text.text), app.close_task_dialog())
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_task_dialog()


<SubTaskDialogContent>:
    id: subtask_content  
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: subtask_text
            hint_text: "Add a subtask ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release:app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_subtask_dialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_subtask()` method is not using the correct key. It is using the `text` from the `MDTextField` instead of the actual key for the task. Try changing:

```
class SubTaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, task_text="", **kwargs):
        super(SubTaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.subtask_text.text = task_text
```

to:

```
class SubTaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, task_text="", key="", **kwargs):
        super(SubTaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.subtask_text.text = task_text
        self.key = key  # remember the correct key
```

The above change remembers the correct key.

And change:

```
<SubTaskDialogContent>:
    id: subtask_content  
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: subtask_text
            hint_text: "Add a subtask ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release:app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_subtask_dialog()
```

to:

```
<SubTaskDialogContent>:
    id: subtask_content  
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: subtask_text
            hint_text: "Add a subtask ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: app.add_subtask(root.key), app.close_subtask_dialog()


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release:app.add_subtask(root.key), app.close_subtask_dialog()
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_subtask_dialog()
```

The above changes to the `kv` pass the correct key to the `add_subtask()` method.